# Select @variable From Where

Tags: sql-server

I have table "q_rank"  with 2 column Q_ID and KTTH

```
q_id    KTTH
1        1
2        1
```

I create this procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    @Param1    varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @query= (SELECT  @Param1 FROM [Exam].[dbo].[q_rank] a where q_id=2)
    SELECT @query

END
```

But when I

```
EXEC test 'KTTH'
```

The result is KTTH, but I want it is 1.
please help me

Comment: Change `SELECT  @Param1` to `select 1`... No really, your question is unclear. What does `1` mean?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I edited the question. 1 is in my "q_rank" table with q_id=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
DECLARE @outval tinyint;

SET @query= 'SELECT @outval = ' + @Param1 + ' FROM [Exam].[dbo].[q_rank] a where q_id=2';
sp_executesql @query, N'@outval tinyint', @outval = @outval output;

return @outval;
```

Comment: sorry for delay, this is the first time I use sp_executesql. It take me hours but finally It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you need Dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    @Param1    varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @query= 'SELECT ' + @Param1  + ' FROM [Exam].[dbo].[q_rank] a where q_id=2'
    exec  (@query)

END
```

Comment: thanks but I want to assign @variable = exec  (@query), this is not working, sorry because I did not write question exactly. My problem is solved :)